# How to model causal relationship between time series in SEM?

Tags: r, time-series, python, structural-equation-modeling

I have some timestamped KPI which I need to identify causal relationship among.

During my literature review I came across Structural Equation Modelling (SEM). I have found some examples both in R and Python and since I am more familiar with Python, I have started working with SEMOPY.

Based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.01140.pdf), this package supports time series but I cannot find any working examples.

Wondering if anyone could share a time series example either in Python or R.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an SEM expert, but have the same problem at the moment. In my opinion, what you could do, is make your data stationary. This probably involves removing trend and seasonality to achieve iid data. The problem is that there still might still be some autocorrelation left in the data and your iid assumption might not hold 100%, but this could get you as close as possible. Anyway, the idea is so remove any time-dependency and then run the SEM. I have not done it yet and you might run into some issues unknown to me at this point, but this is all I can offer. I hope it helps a bit.